# Adding/uploading a file via vtiger 5.4 webservice

Tags: php, vtiger

I'm trying to create a document with an attached filed via the vtiger 5.4 webservice.

Creating a document is straight-forward enough, but I'm not clear on the procedure to add the file.
It seems like a two step process:

1. Upload the file
2. Reference the file to the document

Unless there's a direct way to upload the file alongside the document object, but I can't find any sort of documentation on the subject (other than the basic, barebones webservices docs).

Hoping for any pointers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did not specify which language you are using, so I will paste here a simple curl request that you can try out yourself and figure out how to replicate it in the language of your choice.

Basically, what you need to do is to "attach" the file as `"multipart/form-data"` to the POST request you are sending for creating the new file.

```
curl -i \
-b vtcookies \
-H "Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-X POST \
-F '_operation=saveRecord' \
-F 'module=Documents' \
-F 'session=20a5XXXXXXX9a1ba95c19a' \
-F 'values={"notes_title" : "Example title", "assigned_user_id" : "19x1", "notecontent" : "<p>Some content</p>", "filelocationtype" : "I", "filestatus" : 1, "filename" : "set-your-file-name.png"}' \
-F "file=@\"path-to-filename.png\";filename=\"filename.png\"" \
http://localhost:8888/vtigercrm540/modules/Mobile/api.php
```

Implementation detail for this curl sample: the `-b` options tells curl to look for the session cookie into a file. To make the above curl request work you have to first run the following one:

```
curl -i \
-c vtcookies \
-H "Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-X POST \
-F '_operation=login' \
-F 'username=your-username' \
-F 'password=your-password' \
http://localhost:8888/vtigercrm530/modules/Mobile/api.php
```

Added the following after specifically requesting the question to be concerned with PHP.

Based on the requested PHP language, here are more info.
I played around with the [Vtiger WebService Browser project](http://forge.vtiger.com/projects/vtwsbrowser/) and I can give a couple of more hints (the project is for the Webservices and not for the Mobile API, but offers a PHP client to play with and the underlying concepts are very similar).

The `Vtiger_HTTP_Client` is a subclass of `Curl_HTTP_Client`. Instead of using the `send_post_data` method, you should have a look at `send_multipart_post_data`. In the `HTTP_Client.php` file there is a method called `doPost`. I made a version of it called `doPostFile` that looks like this:

```
function doPostFile($postdata=false, $file, $decodeResponseJSON=false, $timeout=20) {
    if($postdata === false) $postdata = Array();
    $this->debug = TRUE;
    $resdata = $this->send_multipart_post_data($this->_serviceurl, $postdata, $file, null, $timeout);
    if($resdata && $decodeResponseJSON) $resdata = $this->__jsondecode($resdata);
    return $resdata;
}
```

In this code, the `$file` variable contains `$_FILES["file"]` and its `var_dump` looks like:

```
array(6) { ["name"]=> string(28) "@8590567929_72c0ded112_o.jpg" 
["type"]=> string(11) "@image/jpeg" 
["tmp_name"]=> string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpZWMXz5" 
["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(1255732) }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try. I'm using php, but your example helps regardless.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer trying to be more helpful. Please let me know if you think this looks like an acceptable answer

Comment: Super research. Thanks!